# Wait for a specific property of the redux store to update from outside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

Normally what I will do inside a React component is to use the `connect` function to subscribe to the redux store, in that case I have access to the redux store and im aware when it's updating.

I want to wait for the store to update outside from a component , and on a .js file.

Here what I've done so far:

```
//socket-client.js file

import { store } from "../../Redux/store";
//socket.on() function
socket.on(
  "setQuestionsArrayOnTheAccepter",
  async ({ questionsArray, roomNameOnTheStore }) => {

    await store.dispatch(setQuestionsArray(questionsArray)); // this await on the setQuestionArray has no effect
    store.dispatch(setGameProgress());

    const { game } = store.getState();
    const { gameQuestionArray, gameResultArray } = game;

    // gameResultArray = [] will be empty here, and I want the saga to finish before the socket.emit

    socket.emit("sendSetQuestionsArrayOnTheSender", {
      gameQuestionArray,
      gameResultArray,
      roomNameOnTheStore
    });
  }
);
```

The problem is gameResultArray is empty ([]) by default, and from the setQuestionsArray action im dispatching a redux-saga that is a-synchronic and using Axios (the fetchGameResultStart saga)

```
// set QuestionsArray action
export const setQuestionsArray = (
  questionsArray,
  shouldShuffle = true,
  multiplayer = false,
  gameResultArray = null
) => {
  if (shouldShuffle) questionsArray = getRandom(questionsArray, 10);

  // using thunk middelware
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GAME_TYPES.SET_QUESTIONS_ARRAY, payload: questionsArray });

    if (!multiplayer) {
      dispatch(fetchGameResultArrayStart(questionsArray, shouldShuffle));
    } else if (gameResultArray) {
      dispatch(fetchGameResultArraySuccess(gameResultArray));
    }
  };
};
```

So , i want to be able to wait for the fetchGameResultArraySuccess action to be dispatch , and the gameResultArray to be update before running the socket.emit()

Comment: Have you tried middlewares like `redux-saga`?

Comment: I am using saga middlewars, maybe its not clear from the code above. But i'm using sagas from another module,  the single player sagas.  And due to the fact that i need to perform almost the exact operations i dont want to repat the code. The main problem here is that the code is runing on different theards, so im depending on socket.io to notify me that the other player has finished to perform, but this action is not synchronze